# Running container images should have vulnerability findings resolved

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, containers

Getting below vulnerability issues , could you anyone help us how to fix this issues?

Running container images should have vulnerability findings resolved:- Container image vulnerability assessment scans container images running on your Kubernetes clusters for security vulnerabilities and exposes detailed findings for each image. Resolving the vulnerabilities can greatly improve your containers' security posture and protect them from attacks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps you can take to resolve vulnerability findings in your container images:

1. Identify the specific vulnerabilities in your images by running a vulnerability
2. assessment scan. This will give you a detailed report of all the vulnerabilities found in your images.
3. Update the images to the latest version.
4. Use a vulnerability scanning tool that can automatically update your images to the latest version.
5. Use a base image that is regularly updated and has a good security track record.
6. Use a multi-stage build in your Dockerfile to minimize the number of packages and vulnerabilities in your final image
7. Finally, you can use Kubernetes Pod Security Policy